# ls: cannot access file, bad message

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, ls

i can't see the Downloads folder from GUI, a message appear "The location could not be displayed" pointing one pdf file so i enter using the terminal but when i run the ls -l command i see this error

```
-????????? ? ?        ?                 ?            ? 'Antiguo Blanco y Negro Máquina de Escribir Póster.pdf'
```

and if i try to use ls only in that file i got this message

```
ls: cannot access 'Antiguo Blanco y Negro Máquina de Escribir Póster.pdf': Bad message
```

i try as sudo  change the permissions, group and got the same error message.

in the folder i can write new files and see the other files only using the terminal

How can i recover that file?

The path is

> /home/mvelasco/Downloads

My /home it's in a external disk but all the files works perfect, just that file it's the problem

Comment: Can you check if that path is mentioned in `findmnt` and look for weird messages near the end of `dmesg`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: in the **findmnt** it's the /home 

and with dmeseg the last message it's

`[15704.244864] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_lookup:1697: inode #27001936: comm ThreadPoolForeg: iget: checksum invalid`

Comment: Your file system is probably hosed.  Check out [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224673/ext4-fs-error-on-ubuntu-18-04)